# jquery document ready return null but the console are able to get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, episerver

I'm working in a solution inside a CMS (EPiServer).

If I use the console.log to check my object I get a null value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("$('.EPiRequester').html() =" + $('.EPiRequester').html());
}); 

(function myLoop(i) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i + $('.EPiRequester').html());
          if (--i) myLoop(i); 
      }, 3000)
})(10);
```

10 times return null as well.

but if I right in the console to check, the html() method return a value.

```
$('.EPiRequester').html()
"EPi Requester"
```

any idea about this problem?

Comment: can you show html and if possible fiddle demostrating problem

Comment: In your first code you have wrapped with ready handler and that's consoling null (I suppose from somewhere the html is being empty by js) and in your second code, the code is outside the ready handler so it's showing you the html value as before the html is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I changed my method to open the Dialog box. Opening a Dialog with a Iframe I'm able to run all javascript and jQuery.

I didn't understand what was the problem.

```
function openModalFromIframe(that) {
    require(["epi/shell/widget/dialog/Dialog"], function (Dialog) {

        var url = $(that).attr('data-iframe-url');
        var title = $(that).attr('data-title');

        var dialog = new Dialog({
            Title: title,
            loadingMessage: "Loading...",
            defaultActionsVisible: false,
            preventCache: true,
            style: "width: 800px; ",
        });
        dialog.attr("content", '<iframe src="' + url + '" style=" width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;"></iframe>');
        dialog.show();
    });
}
```

If someone get the same issue here are my workaround.

Answer (score 1):

> ...I get a null value...

Neither `$()` nor `html()` ever returns `null`. I assume you mean either that `$('.EPiRequester')` returns an empty jQuery object, or that `$('.EPiRequester').html()` returns `undefined` (as opposed to `""`).

`html()` will only return `undefined` if you call it on an empty jQuery set. So this tells us that the `.EPiRequester` element is added to the page dynamically by the CMS sometime *after* the jQuery `ready` event fires. It may even be triggered by `ready` (e.g., the CMS code waiting for `ready` before doing some `ajax` call to fill in something that doesn't have to be delivered with the main page content).

Ideally, the CMS should give you some other event you can respond to when all the content is there. If not, and this is very much a second-class option, you can use a repeated `setTimeout` to deal with it:

```
$(document).ready(useEPiRequester); 
function useEPiRequester() {
    var elm = $('.EPiRequester');
    if (elm[0]) {
        // It's there now, use it...
    } else {
        // Not there yet, wait a bit longer
        setTimeout(useEPiRequester, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this code are in infinite loop.

Comment: @AFetter: Then the element never exists. If that's a possibility, you can easily add a counter.